# Exiftool mp4 metadata python

Tags: python, exiftool

I have code to change the mediacreated date for mp4 meta data with the following code

```
    cmd = [exiftool_path, "-overwrite_original","-CreateDate={}".format(new_date), directory_file_name]
```

i noticed that sometimes that the media created in the file explorer details tab that it'll sometimes not be there. i verified using exiftool that the mediacreated date was changed successfully and uploaded to amazon photos and see that the date taken is the create date that i modified. Which is good.

But why can't i see it when i go to the file explorer properties details menu? how can i have it appear there or is there another tag that i can write to that will appear as well?

edit here's the function that modifys the mp4 date with exif tool

```
def modify_mp4_date(formatted_date_input,file_list_number):
directory_file_name = file_directory + "/" + file_list[file_list_number]
print("directory_file_name")
print(directory_file_name)
print("this is pic number")
print(file_list_number+1)

# specify the path to the exiftool executable
exiftool_path = r"C:\Windows\exiftool.exe"

# specify the file path and the new date
#time is set to 12am, automatically adds +7 hours to time 12-7=5
time = "05:00:00"

# time = "00:00:00"

new_date = formatted_date_input + " " + time

print("MP4 Date")
print(new_date)

# construct the command to change the date
cmd = [exiftool_path, "-overwrite_original","-CreateDate={}".format(new_date), directory_file_name]
# cmd = [exiftool_path, "-overwrite_original","-Quicktime:CreateDate={}".format(new_date), directory_file_name]

# call exiftool to change the date
subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    
print("Modified mp4 media create date YEEHAW!")

#confirm data
output = subprocess.check_output([exiftool_path, "-CreateDate", "-b", directory_file_name])
creation_date = output.decode().strip()

print("Creation date from file")
# print(f"Creation date from file: {creation_date}")
print(creation_date)

#check if data is the same
if new_date == creation_date:
    print("Successful Write")

    #move file to different folder when done
    # shutil.move(src, dst)
else:
    print("Write Failed")
    sys.exit("MP4 write failed")
```

function for the user data

```
def take_user_input():
user_input = input("Enter Date Taken: ")
input_string = str(user_input)
print(input_string)

#USER INPUT MM DD YYYY
#formats to YYYY MM DD
formatted_date = input_string[4:8] + ":" + input_string[:2] + ":" + input_string[2:4]

#USER INPUT YYYY MM DD
#YYYY MM DD
#formatted_date = input_string[:4] + ":" + input_string[4:6] + ":" + input_string[6:8]
print(formatted_date)

return formatted_date
```

before

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf3Kz.png)

after

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuzqP.png)

Comment: What's the format of the date you're sending?

Comment: like this @Destroy666 1980:01:01 12:00:00

Comment: Looks correct. I couldn't reproduce the problem myself though on multiple random mp4s in my Windows 10. You would need to show more of the code, e.g. where `new_date` is defined. Or share a specific .mp4 that doesn't work. You could also try overwriting `-FileCreateDate`, which Windows uses by default for files, but I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: @Destroy666 ok i added more info let me know if you need any other additional info. The problem with this its intermittent so sometimes it'll show the change correctly and sometimes it won't. i'm using windows 10. i tried using windows 11 and date/time shows but it seems shifted for some reason.

Comment: Because the date/time should be in UTC according to specification - you need to convert it. Not sure if that's also causing the WIndows 10 issue of it not being present sometimes, but the Windows 11 issue is definitely caused by that.

Comment: `formatted_date = input_string[4:8] + ":" + input_string[:2] + ":" + input_string[2:4]` is not expecting spaces. Your input format should be MMDDYYYY. Ran your code and this works. Side note the `DateTimeOriginal` tag trumps `CreateDate` in Windows systems; incase this doesn't end up changing the date on some files.

Comment: If you're still having issues with some files please collect/print the error output from ExifTool (`output.stderr` from your run cmd).

Comment: ok so for a .mp4 you need to give it the utc of when it was taken and the computer will adjust the date according to its time zone and display it adjusted. also larger .mp4s have problem with displaying the tags (sometimes it disappears)  smaller ones dont seem to have that problem